# Probability of winning a tennis match

Tags: probability

I have been in the process of looking at this url here - https://www.betfair.com.au/hub/news/tennis/tennis-modelling-point-based-models/ to look into a model of finding out the probability of a player winning a tennis match.

The thing I don't understand though is that the formula to me doesn't make any sense.

**[fi - fav]** = the players probability of winning a point on serve minus the tennis average

**[gi - gav]** = the players probability of winning a point on return of serve minus the tennis average.

This I all understand, however when I do the calculations, the numbers don't come up the same as in article.

For instance **fi** (70.44% for Djokovic) **- fav** (64%) **= 6.44**

Also

**gi** (44.6% for Djkovic) **- gav** (36%) **= 8.6**

Now for Federer

**fi** (72.3 for Federer) **- fav** (64%) **= 8.3**

also

**gi** (41.1 for Federer) **- gav** (36%) **= 5.1**

Now that we have those calculations I now do the entire formula.

**ft** which is (67.2%) **+ (fi - fav) - (gi - gav) = 70.4** for Federer

**ft** which is (67.2%) **+ (fi - fav) - (gi - gav) = 65.04** for Djokovic.

Totally different numbers than mentioned on the paper where it says.

> Putting all this together using Barnett and Clarke’s equation, we find
>   that it predicts serve-winning probabilities of 67.0% for Roger
>   Federer and 68.6% for Novak Djokovic.

I don't know where they got those numbers from as I believe I have done the calculation correct. None of this makes sense.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. I really don't understand this at all. I feel like I have done everything correctly.